# Get current day values from database to plot on highcharts

Tags: mysql, json, date, graph, highcharts

Hello i am designing a webserver which shows me a power consumption graph from a mysql database. I am a beginner and have written a code with some help that uses ajax calls to fetch the data from the database and plot it on the highcharts. Problem is that I get all the historic values saved in my database but I want only the values of current day to be plotted on the chart. This is my js code:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 100
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'POWER'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Power Consumption',
        data: (function () {
            var data = [], i, t, d;

            var request = {};
                request['EndPoint'] = "arduino/charts/analog/fetch";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Server/fyp-processor.php",
                    data: JSON.stringify(request),
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.Code == "1008" && (result.Data != null || result.Data != undefined)) {
                            for(i = 0; i < result.Data.Historic.length; i++) {
                                t = result.Data.Historic[i].DateTime.split(/[- :]/);
                                d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);

                                data.push({
                                    x: d,
                                    y: parseInt(result.Data.Historic[i].Value)
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

It calls a fyp-processor php script that contains this code:

```
else if($postData['EndPoint'] == 'arduino/charts/analog/fetch') {
#result set
$resultSet = null;

#get all historic analog chart data
$results = $db->charts();

if(count($results) > 0) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $resultSet['Historic'][] = $result;
    }
}
```

I would be glad if anyone could help me out to get only current DAY's data and also what changes I can do to it then to get current month and current week's data too.

Comment: where is your mysql query for fetching data

Comment: the fyp-proccessor.php is fetching all of the data

Comment: i am actually asking about database query ...  i cant see any db query there ...

Comment: Why you cannot use sql query limited by current day? It is more efficient.

Comment: I am sorry am a beginner to this php and sql things.. i also got all this code by using my friend's help. Can you please elaborate how can i use an sql query limited by current day???